# How to change navbar list item background color when it is selected?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change background color of selected tab or visited page in navbar, I see bootstrap css how they have background color on hover and visited but i am not sure if i should overwrite bootstrap css or add helper class to acheive this task.

main.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div >
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a ui-sref="app.dit">DIT</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="app.st">ST</a>
                <li><a>UAT</a></li>
                <li><a>PROD</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

In both ways you will override Bootstrap.
CSS changes you need to apply are:

```
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: green;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: green;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: red;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: I only want to highlight current visited tab as soon as user navigate to other page tab should go to default Also its only changing text color can we change background as well.

Comment: /* selected link */
a:active {
    background-color: yellow;
}

Comment: this is just hover background-color should stay active till user on current page